# Axios en archivo externo del componente

Tags: javascript, vue.js

tengo un componente con muchas llamadas a API, y me gustaría extraerlas aun fichero aparte, el problema es que lo importo y las invoco y no se hace nada, he utilizado async/await y sigue sin hacer nada.
/en el componente, de forma resumida

```
import getData from './utils';
[...]
   
     created() {
       
        this.getProfile();
      
      },
      methods: {
      async getProfile() {
      try{
         await getData;
      }catch
         console.error('error')
      }
    },
        },
```

En el fichero utils.vue:

```
     const getData=()=> {
      var vm = this;
     

      var config = {
        method: "get",
        url: profileApiUrl,
        dataType: "json",
        headers: {
          "Content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          Authorization: "Bearer " + window.localStorage.getItem("_token"),
        },
      };

      axios(config)
        .then(function (response) {
          try {
              console.log(responde.data)
              return response.data;
            
          } catch (error) {
               console.error(error)
          }
        
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.error(error)
        });
    },

export default getData;
```

Y no hace nada, no da error, ni visualizo la petición en el debug del navegador.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pero no estás ejecutando el getData() que está dentro del método getProfile()